# Нужно ли наращение?

Tags: наращение

...по итогам уходящего года и перспектив года 2020-го.
Нужно ли наращение?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ...**когда при указании даты название месяца или года** опущено, или **поставлено перед датой**, или отделено от даты частицей, то **наращения уместны** (числа 10-го, **год 1980-й**, с 19 мая по 20-е, в 20-х числах).

См. [**Наращение окончаний к числительным в цифровой форме в русском языке**](https://ru.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BA_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC_%D0%B2_%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B5_%D0%B2_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC_%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B5).

> ...**если слово год** или название месяца опущено или **поставлено перед числом**, падежное окончание **рекомендуется наращивать**. Напр.: в мае, числа 20-го; **год 1920-й**; Грянул 1917-й.

См. [**Отсутствие наращения падежного окончания**](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0/%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%81%D1%83%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F/).